# In Inno Setup, how can I set the text color of the text in an input field?

Tags: colors, inno-setup

In Inno Setup, I want to display the user input text in red if it is an invalid value.  (As determined by me, elsewhere.)

Comment: What is that input field ? Is that an edit box, item in an input query page, or... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to set the `Font.Color` property of the edit of your choice. For instance, to change the edit font color immediately when the text changes, you can write a handler for the `OnChange` event, in code it might be something like this:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  CustomEdit: TNewEdit;

procedure CustomEditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TEdit then
  begin
    { the font color will be changed to red when the user enters more }
    { than 3 chars in the edit, to default color otherwise; rules for }
    { this statement are upon you }
    if Length(TEdit(Sender).Text) > 3 then
      TEdit(Sender).Font.Color := clRed
    else
      TEdit(Sender).Font.Color := clWindowText;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  CustomEdit := TNewEdit.Create(CustomPage);
  CustomEdit.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  CustomEdit.OnChange := @CustomEditChange;
end;
```

If you would like to validate the input when the user exits the edit box, you can write similar handler for the `OnExit` event.